# Open Graph works well with https but not with http

Tags: facebook, ssl, facebook-opengraph

I debugged my website with facebook debugger. The websites has a SSL certificate installed. When I share a link on facebook with https in the begining of the url, everything works well. If I post it with http, it's not working well - no title, description and a random image from website.

I tried to debug the "http" url too, but There's and error "The 'og:type' property is required, but not present."

Please Help

Comment: [link](https://titot.pl)

Comment: Anybody can help me?